# spacy - How to make POS tagger work for russian language?

Tags: spacy

In [russian language](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/647f2544c5dcf816bcb065d46621bf0d7553ed64/spacy/lang/ru/__init__.py#L26) the class variable `tag_map` is properly set, pymorphy2 provide detailed grammatical tags, but the following example doesn't work:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('ru')
doc = nlp('Я люблю яблоки')
print(doc[0].pos_, doc[0].tag_) # prints '', ''
```

Information about environment:

```
Models             en, ru
spaCy version      2.0.11
Platform           Linux-4.4.0-116-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
Python version     3.5.2
Location           /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy
```

Comment: As I know , Spacy doesn't have a Russian model, the link you refereed here is Russian language prerequisites and it isn't `ru` model.  You should train a Russian model yourself.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ Are there any news about it? Maybe you know about some already trained models?

Does it mean Russian library consist only tokenizer without lemmatizer?

Comment: See spacy github for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can download and use russian model `ru2` from [this project](https://github.com/buriy/spacy-ru). It will work.